# Having two custom views of same class in layout causes first to not work

Tags: android

If I put two custom views of the same class in a layout, the first view doesn't seem to respond, while the second view works fine. Could someone explain why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:joystick="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.omletinapan.PPPad"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
<com.lation.multimote.analog
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        joystick:pos_x="30.0"
        joystick:pos_y="60.0"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
<com.lation.multimote.analog
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        joystick:pos_x="450.0"
        joystick:pos_y="60.0"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem not to have defined the relative positions of the two layouts in the relativelayout. Seems first one is hidden by second one.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not quite sure I understand. At the moment, those x and y values dictate where on the screen the images are being drawn. I've tried aligning the views next to each other within the XML, but that doesn't seem to work. If you could explain more, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: There is no orientation in RelativeLayout. Please try AbsoluteLayout

Comment: Changing to linear layout causes one of the views to not be drawn. I just realized that the x and y coordinates simply move the bitmap - the layout dictates where it's placed. I've changed the x and y positions for both views to 0, but only one shows.

Comment: what about Absolutelayout with the original positions in your problem?

Comment: It works exactly as expected in AbsoluteLayout. I'll have to see if I can get it working in the other layouts, but at least I know that both views are working!